# Moving data from one table to other

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I am working on cassandra. I have two tables. Table `A` and `B`. In Table A there are two columns `id`, `name`. In `Table B` there are two columns `id` and `personname`. 
I need to migrate data from `table A` to `B` where data from name in `table A` should go to personname in `Table B`.
 Could you help me on this.

My Approach is:

1. CREATE a `table B`;
2. get the resultset of `tableA`
3. Dump the row contents (When i dump row contents say ID AND NAME)
4. write all the captured fields to `table b`  (When capturing data name doesnot exist here. So ? do I work here.)
5. drop `table A`
6. getresult set to `table B`
7. DUMP out the row contents

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that id is the primary key in both tables, you can do the followings from cqlsh:

```
COPY A TO 'a.csv';
COPY B FROM 'a.csv';
```

Hope this helps.